# Facebook API show popin message when posting picture

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

i want to post a picture on a user wall from my website.
The user is already connected, and I use this method:

```
FB.api('/me/photos', 'post', {
        message: "my message",
        url:sourceimage
    }, function(response){
        if (!response || response.error) {
            console.log(response);
        } else {
            alert("image is posted");
        }

  });
```

Now I want to know how I can prompt the Facebook popin so that the user is able to change his message before sending it to facebook ?

Thanks

Comment: You can't. You will have to show the popup your self and ask for the message

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As WizKid said, not possible with FB.api.

Comment: Would like to know why i get -1.